# Confusing message "error: inflate error data error" when trying to unzip

Tags: inflate

I am trying to unzip a zipped archive that only has 1 text file in it (around 30-40 mb let's say).

I keep getting the following error for some reason and I don't know how to make any sense of it!

```
error: inflate error data error
 at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0/Archive/Zip/Member.pm line 862
        Archive::Zip::Member::_inflateChunk('Archive::Zip::ZipFileMember=HASH(0x95022a8)', 'SCALAR(0x9400a88)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0/Archive/Zip/Member.pm line 798
        Archive::Zip::Member::readChunk('Archive::Zip::ZipFileMember=HASH(0x95022a8)', 32768) called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0/Archive/Zip/Member.pm line 1063
        Archive::Zip::Member::_writeData('Archive::Zip::ZipFileMember=HASH(0x95022a8)', 'IO::File=GLOB(0x9502688)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0/Archive/Zip/Member.pm line 991
        Archive::Zip::Member::extractToFileHandle('Archive::Zip::ZipFileMember=HASH(0x95022a8)', 'IO::File=GLOB(0x9502688)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0/Archive/Zip/Member.pm line 488
        Archive::Zip::Member::extractToFileNamed('Archive::Zip::ZipFileMember=HASH(0x95022a8)', '/home/websync/3rdParties/SDCDcatalogs//90000LeadingEdge_Catal...') called at grabsdcd.pl line 39
```

Does anyone know what is up with this message? Is it something I am doing wrong or is the file corrupted by itself?

Thanks!

Comment: This happens each and every time to me. It's a different HASH though. I really can't figure this one out.... extracting on a different computer with WinZip seems to work fine, but the point is I want to automate this process and have it unzip in a Perl script...

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because the zip file had been downloaded as ascii. Once I'd set the download to binary the problem went away.

Net::FTP

```
$ftp->binary();
$ftp->get.......
```

NB: 'binary' goes just before the 'get'